# Animate an element to slide over others and stretch to a set width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-animate

I have a table of headings and when one of the headings is clicked I want it to first stretch to the width of the table and then slide down over the others.  When it is clicked again or another heading is clicked, any open one should return to its original state.

I have the following HTML:

```
<table style="width: 100%;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td width='50%'>
                <center class='buttons headings'>H1</center>
                <div class='hidden'>some text</div>
            </td>
            <td width='50%'>
                <center class='buttons headings'>H2</center>
                <div class='hidden'>some text</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width='50%'>
                <center class='buttons headings'>H3</center>
                <div class='hidden'>some text</div>
            </td>
            <td width='50%'>
                <center class='buttons headings'>H4</center>
                <div class='hidden'>some text</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

My jQuery so far is as follows:

```
$(".headings").click(function(){
    $(this).animate({width: "199%",
                     position: "relative",
                     top: "+=50px"
                    }, 1000);
    $(this).next().slideToggle(100);
});
```

This successfully stretches the heading though doesn't move it down.  I'm really not sure why, any help is fantastic, thank you!

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z7txdbbh/)

Comment: can you create a fiddle in order to show us exactly what you mean because it is a little confusing

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/z7txdbbh/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/z7txdbbh/

Answer (score 0):

To correctly use `top`, you need to also use `position`

```
.headings{
   position:relative;
  }
```

To undo the animation, use flag logic like

```
$(".headings").attr('data-undo', false);
    $(".headings").click(function(){
      var width = '100%', top = '-=50px';
      var undo = $(this).attr('data-undo') == 'true';
      if(!undo){
        width = '199%'; 
        top = '+=50px';
        }
      ...
      $(this).attr('data-undo', !undo);
     });
```

```js
$(".headings").attr('data-undo', false);
$(".headings").click(function(){
  var width = '100%', top = '-=100px';
  var undo = $(this).attr('data-undo') == 'true';
  console.log(undo);
  if(!undo){
    width = '199%'; 
    top = '+=100px';
    }
    
    $(this).animate({width: width,
                     top: top
                     
                    }, 1000);
    $(this).next().slideToggle(100);
  $(this).attr('data-undo', !undo);
});
```

```css
.headings{
   position:relative;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="width: 100%;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td width='50%'>
                <center class='buttons headings'>H1</center>
                <div class='hidden'>some text</div>
            </td>
            <td width='50%'>
                <center class='buttons headings'>H2</center>
                <div class='hidden'>some text</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width='50%'>
                <center class='buttons headings'>H3</center>
                <div class='hidden'>some text</div>
            </td>
            <td width='50%'>
                <center class='buttons headings'>H4</center>
                <div class='hidden'>some text</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @Eoin, so this is not what you want. What do you want?

Comment: heading I click on, extends to width of table and slides down over the other td elements to display underneath them......when clicked on again, it should return to original position and length

Comment: ah yes, thank you, that works nicely, is it possible to move the td below the table though? this part I cant seem to get with the position: relative and top: '+=50px' elements

Comment: Wouldnt it move the table if you increased top to say +=100 or am I misunderstanding here? See the updated snippet demo

Comment: On my page for some reason the td heading I click on still doesnt budge and also the line where you had undo = !undo works but the new one >> $(this).attr('data-undo', !undo); doesn't for me

Comment: @Eoin, did you update all the code? Does an error occur in the console?

Comment: no errors in the console, but still not working for me, I've tried appending it into the new row but I cant seem to get it to go back to the original configuration.....very frustrating...

Comment: @Eoin, can you reproduce the problem in a fiddle?